# Showing new lines(\n) in PD Dataframe String

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, newline

I am trying to create a dataframe that has one column that contains a string of texts that has lines. Those lines are separated by lines so that they are easily readable.

```
string=['''
    hello all:. I request the following from you:


    do the laundry:
    sleep early
    wake up early
    feed the chicken

     ''']


ii=pd.DataFrame(string, columns=['requirement'])
ii
```

However, when I generate the dataframe, the table shows very messy and all the new lines are separated by (\n) in text format.

> \nhello all:. I request the following from you:\n\n\ndo the laundry:\nsleep early\nwake up early\nfeed the chicken\n\n

How do I preserve the lines inside of the PD Dataframe so that it is easily readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A robust way is to use [`tabulate`](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/):

```
# pip install tabulate

from tabulate import tabulate

print(tabulate(ii, tablefmt='plain', headers=list(ii)))
```

Output:

```
    requirement
 0  hello all:. I request the following from you:


        do the laundry:
        sleep early
        wake up early
        feed the chicken
```

Other example:

```
ii = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['123\nABCDE\n\n\nF', '12\n3'],
                   'B': [1, 2],
                   'C': ['ABC', 'A\nB\nC']})`
```

Output:

```
    A        B  C
 0  123      1  ABC
    ABCDE


    F
 1  12       2  A
    3           B
                C
```

###### as HTML

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML(ii.to_html().replace('\\n', '<br>')))
```

Output:

example 1:

[image: pandas HTML table with newlines]

example 2:

[image: pandas HTML table with newlines]

##### alignment

```
print(tabulate(ii, tablefmt='plain', headers=list(ii), stralign='left'))

        A    B    C
 0  123      1  ABC
    ABCDE


    F
 1  12       2  A
    3           B
                C


print(tabulate(ii, tablefmt='plain', headers=list(ii), stralign='right'))

        A    B    C
 0    123    1  ABC
    ABCDE


        F
 1     12    2    A
        3         B
                  C
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I wanted. Do you knw how to make the text nice and start from the left?

Comment: @Mohammed I'm afraid that you would need to write a small function to left-justify the string (split on \n, get the max substring length, pad with this length).

Comment: I found out I can 'left-justify' using pandas style.set_properties. However, whenever I do that,  all the '\n' disappear from the text so I cannot use HTML to break new line using the replace function. It is almost I have to choose either or!!

Comment: Can you try: `ii.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left', 'white-space': 'pre-wrap'})`

Comment: And to change the alignment with `tabulate`: `print(tabulate(ii, tablefmt='plain', headers=list(ii), stralign='right'))`

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
ii['requirement'].replace('\n', '', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```py
import re

string=['''
    hello all:. I request the following from you:


    do the laundry:
    sleep early
    wake up early
    feed the chicken

     ''']
string = [re.sub('(\n+)(\s+)',' ',s).strip() for s in string]

ii=pd.DataFrame(string, columns=['requirement'])
ii
```